# Two pointers point to the same refernce

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a question about the pointers

I have two pointers, one is initialized and the other is not;

Now i want the second pointer that has no value (is not initialized yet) to point to the same place in the memory.

OK, i wrote a small program to do this and it works correctly

```
int *P , *P2 ; 
P = new int ; 
P2 = new int ; 

*P = 1 ; 
P2 = P ; 
cout << "P= " << *P << endl << endl ; 
cout << "P2= " << *P2 << endl << endl ; 

*P = 0 ;
cout << "P2= " << *P2 << endl << endl ;
```

The output is like this:

```
P = 1 ; 
P2 = 1 ; 

P2 = 0 ;
```

So it work correct like i want.

Now i want to do the same but this time i want to do it using `ID3D11Device *`

Here is the code:

```
 ID3D11Device *Test ;
 Test = Device->Get_Device() ; 


cout << "Test =" << Test << endl << endl ; 
cout << "Get = " << Device->Get_Device()<< endl << endl ; 


Device->~CL_Device();

cout << "Test =" << Test << endl << endl ; 
cout << "Get = " << Device->Get_Device()<< endl << endl ;
```

Get_Device function definition :

```
![ID3D11Device  *const Get_Device()  const     { return  _Device ;}][1]
```

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwD0d.png) explaining what i want.

Comment: Is there a question I'm missing?

Comment: Do not use  `P2 = new int` and then point to another memory location without `delete`ing the old value.

Comment: Your first example has a memory leak. You allocate a new int: `P2 = new int;`, but don't `delete` it before reassigning the pointer: `P2 = P;`. So that int remains allocated until the program terminates, wasting memory. It's not much, just an int, but they quickly add up, especially if allocated in loops.

Comment: You have const issues there. Not consistent between method and use.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should avoid calling the destructor of an object directly. That does not free the memory associated with it. Use `delete Device;` instead.

Secondly, if you want two pointers you simply have to proceed as you hav shown in your first example:

```
ID3D11Device *Test, *Test2;
Test = Device->Get_Device();
Test2 = Test;
```

now `Test`, `Test2` and `Device->Get_Device()` all point to the same location in the memory of course only if `Device->Get_Device()` returns always the same pointer.

EDIT: see comment

Comment: +1 Never is a strong word, but in this case I agree :)

Comment: Thanks, you are of course right, in some situation it does indeed make sense.